# Sending ARP request throw the WiFi

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, wifi, arp

I'm trying to do an ARP scanning over the WiFi. I'm getting the list of available network interfaces like this:

```
def GetListOfAvailableNetworkInterfaces():

    Result = None
    c = wmi.WMI()
    qry = "select Name from Win32_NetworkAdapter where NetEnabled = True and 
    NetConnectionStatus = 2"
    Result = [o.Name for o in c.query(qry)]
    return Result
```

When i'm connected by WiFi, i'm getting this interface name:

```
Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165.
```

I checked via route print - such interface exists. get_if_list () returns the same, from which I conclude that the interface is valid. I send the ARP request like this:

```
 srp( Ether( dst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff" ) / ARP( pdst = "192.168.0.0/24" ), timeout = 2, verbose = 0, iface = GetListOfAvailableNetworkInterfaces()[0])
```

The problem is that the answers do not come, but if i do everything the same, but with the cable on, answers comes, here's the adapter I get with the cable connected:

```
Qualcomm Atheros AR8171/8175 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
```

In the specified range of addresses, there are guaranteed hosts. What do I do wrong in the case of a wireless connection?

My OS: Windows 10 x64

Comment: Do you have an access point with client isolation?

Comment: Just checked it out - i haven't